# Error 404 when post request Spring boot and Flutter app

Tags: flutter, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, login-page

I try to create a mobile login page using Springboot and Flutter technologies. I am new in development.
Tomcat started normally and connected to db. I use emulator pixel 4 api 31 to test my app.

Is url [http://192.168.2.6:8090/users/login'](http://192.168.2.6:8090/users/login%27) in dart file correct? When login button pressed
`I/flutter ( 7730): Error: 404` appeared.

I aslo try to change in login_page.dart file the url to 'http://localhost:8090/users/login', 'http://127.0.0.1:8090/users/login' and http://'127.0.0.2':8090/users/login' but I get a connection refused error.
Here is the code:

App.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("org.example.repository.*")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "org.example.controller.*" })
@EntityScan("org.example.model.*")
public class App
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

UserController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")

public class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;
    private UserMapper userMapper; // Inject UserMapper here

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/register") // in mobile app doesn't need all users should be registered by corresponding gym
    public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> registerUser(@RequestBody UserDTO userDTO) {
        // Receive and validate userDTO from the client

        // Map userDTO to a User entity
        User userEntity = userService.registerUser(userDTO);

        // Map the resulting User entity to a UserDTO for the response
        UserDTO registeredUserDTO = UserMapper.mapToDTO(userEntity);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(registeredUserDTO);
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> loginUser(@RequestBody UserDTO userDTO) throws AuthenticationException {
        // Validate the loginRequest, e.g., check for null values

        // Map userDTO to a User entity
        UserDTO loginUserDTO = userService.loginUser(userDTO);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(loginUserDTO);
    }
```

application.properties

```
server.port=8090
server.tomcat.threads.max=200
server.connection-timeout=5s
server.max-http-header-size=8KB
server.tomcat.max-swallow-size=2MB
server.tomcat.max-http-post-size=2MB
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdbgymapp?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

login_page.dart (Flutter app)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

import 'home_page.dart';

class LoginDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginDemoState createState() => _LoginDemoState();
}

class _LoginDemoState extends State<LoginDemo> {
  final TextEditingController usernameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

  Future<void> loginUser() async {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('http://192.168.2.6:8090/users/login'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        'username': usernameController.text,
        'password': passwordController.text,
      }),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // Successful login
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => HomePage()));
    } else if (response.statusCode == 400) {
      // Invalid username or password
      print('Invalid username or password');
    } else {
      // Handle other error cases
      print('Error: ${response.statusCode}');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Login Page"),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 60.0),
              child: Center(
                child: Container(
                    width: 200,
                    height: 150,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.red,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0)),
                    child: Image.asset('asset/images/gymApp-logo.png')),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              //padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:15.0,right: 15.0,top:0,bottom: 0),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Email',
                    hintText: 'Enter valid email id as abc@gmail.com'),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 15.0, right: 15.0, top: 15, bottom: 0),
              //padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
              child: TextField(

                obscureText: true,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Password',
                    hintText: 'Enter secure password'),
              ),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: (){
                //TODO FORGOT PASSWORD SCREEN GOES HERE
              },
              child: Text(
                'Forgot Password',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 15),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 50,
              width: 250,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.blue, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                        child: TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  loginUser();
                },
                child: Text(
                  'Login',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 130,
            ),
            Text('New User? Create Account')
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Tomcat logs

> 2023-09-14T10:38:53.779+03:00  INFO 288 --- [  restartedMain] org.example.App                          : Starting App using Java 17.0.8 with PID 288 (C:\Users\giorg\IdeaProjects\gymApp\target\classes started by Λιτσα in C:\Users\giorg\IdeaProjects\gymApp)
> 2023-09-14T10:38:53.782+03:00  INFO 288 --- [  restartedMain] org.example.App                          : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
> 2023-09-14T10:38:53.864+03:00  INFO 288 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
> 2023-09-14T10:38:53.864+03:00  INFO 288 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
> 2023-09-14T10:38:55.143+03:00  INFO 288 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
> 2023-09-14T10:38:55.159+03:00  INFO 288 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 8 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
> 2023-09-14T10:38:56.647+03:00  INFO 288 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8090 (http)
> 2023-09-14T10:38:56.669+03:00  INFO 288 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
> 2023-09-14T10:38:56.669+03:00  INFO 288 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.5]
> 2023-09-14T10:38:56.787+03:00  INFO 288 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
> 2023-09-14T10:38:56.788+03:00  INFO 288 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2923 ms
> 2023-09-14T10:38:56.818+03:00  INFO 288 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
> 2023-09-14T10:38:57.185+03:00  INFO 288 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@2cf75a85
> 2023-09-14T10:38:57.186+03:00  INFO 288 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
> 2023-09-14T10:38:57.196+03:00  INFO 288 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdbgymapp?serverTimezone=UTC'
> 2023-09-14T10:38:57.461+03:00  INFO 288 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
> 2023-09-14T10:38:57.676+03:00  INFO 288 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.7.Final
> 2023-09-14T10:38:57.963+03:00  INFO 288 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
> 2023-09-14T10:38:58.141+03:00  INFO 288 --- [  restartedMain] SQL dialect                              : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
> 2023-09-14T10:38:58.537+03:00  INFO 288 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
> 2023-09-14T10:38:58.548+03:00  INFO 288 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
> 2023-09-14T10:38:58.761+03:00  WARN 288 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
> 2023-09-14T10:38:59.336+03:00  INFO 288 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
> 2023-09-14T10:38:59.366+03:00  INFO 288 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8090 (http) with context path ''
> 2023-09-14T10:38:59.375+03:00  INFO 288 --- [  restartedMain] org.example.App                          : Started App in 6.016 seconds (process running for 6.52)
> 2023-09-14T10:51:26.685+03:00  WARN 288 --- [l-1 housekeeper] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Thread starvation or clock leap detected (housekeeper delta=1m59s220ms870µs300ns).
> 2023-09-14T10:53:55.076+03:00  INFO 288 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
> 2023-09-14T10:53:55.077+03:00  INFO 288 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
> 2023-09-14T10:53:55.079+03:00  INFO 288 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms

Answer (score 0):

To test the API, you can use the following `curl` command in your terminal:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/users/login
```

If both the server and your machine are running locally, the IP address is typically `localhost` and not an address like `192.168.x.x`.

For those using an Android Emulator, please refer to the networking documentation for more details on network addresses:
[Android Emulator Networking Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking#networkaddresses)

Comment: I also attached logs from Tomcat if they are helpful. Thank you

Comment: I tried curl with localhost, 127.0.01 and ipv4 but cannot connect. With ipv4 "curl: (28) Failed to connect to 192.168.2.6 port 8090 after 21053 ms: Couldn't connect to server" and with localhost and 127.0.0.1 {"timestamp":"2023-09-14T08:15:06.892+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/users/login"}

Comment: your response message says that you do not have an endpoint under `/users/login`. 

this can only be that you have not tested with `POST` or spring has not registered the endpoint.

but the 404 tells you that you are on the right track.

Comment: I try to identify the problem without entiites and db only with controllers. i use @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "org.example.controller.*" }) and again white page error appeared. When removed * works correctly (@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "org.example.controller or @ComponentScan("org.example.controller"). Then I try this with entities @SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("org.example.repository")
@ComponentScan(value = "org.example.controller" )
@EntityScan("org.example.model"), ->Error creating bean with name 'userRepository Not a managed type: class org.example.model.User